# Positive Semidefinite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are both positive semidefinite matrices, define matrix $C$, and $C(i,j)$ = $A(i,j) \times B(i,j)$. Is $C$ positive semidefinite ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called the schur product theorem. Read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem)